# Using PreparedStatement template issue

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

Here's my static utility:

```
 //String sqlQuery = "select count(name) as num from tbname where name = ?"
    //String name = "testString";

    private static int correct(Connection connection, String sqlQuery, String name) {
        int result = 0;
        PreparedStatement statatement = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            statatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
            statatement.setString(1, name);
            rs = statatement.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                result = rs.getInt("num");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                rs.close();
                statatement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

The method above returns 0 (incorrect result), but the following one returns '1' (it works OK, it the same sql query):

```
//String sqlQuery = "select count(name) as num from tbname where name = 'testString'"

    private static int correct(Connection connection, String sqlQuery, String name) {
        int result = 0;
        PreparedStatement statatement = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            statatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
            rs = statatement.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                result = rs.getInt("num");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                rs.close();
                statatement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Could you please give me any advise, so I could resolve the problem.

PS: I'm not sure if it does matter, but the actual streetName - has a name in windows-1251 encoding (Russian) text.
PPS: The database is Oracle 10.

Comment: You've stated some facts but not told us what the problem is yet...

Comment: When I ran sql query via setting sql template (statement.setString(1, name) it does not work correctly. When I ran the same sql query as dynamic it does work.

Comment: What does show SQL editor with this query? (try SQL Developer or similar tool).

Comment: Is there any `SQLException` dumped to the error output? (The code does have issues with error handling and resource management.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the encoding conflict with the one which you set in your DB encoding charset and the the String you are passing..

You can do these 2 tries

1. Set the DB encoding to UTF-8 and then give a try. If this does not work you may go with following 2nd option
2. Set DB encoding charset to UTF-8 and also set the String by using this String constructor `String(byte[] bytes, String charsetName)`

Answer (score 0):

It might be a character set issue. According to the [Oracle JDBC Drivers release 10.1.0.2.0 (10g) README](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-readme101020-089859.html):

> The following is a list of known
>   problems/limitations:
>
> - If the database character set is AL32UTF8, you may see errors under the
>     following circumstances:
>
>   - accessing LONG and VARCHAR2 datatypes.
>   - binding data with setString() and setCharacterStream().

So if your database character set is AL32UTF8, you might have to get it changed to something else.

Also, what is the datatype of your column? VARCHAR2?